# На хостинге не видны "внутренние" стили

Tags: css

https://codepen.io/phenax/pen/XbOvpw

В codepen все работает. 
Стили, которые внутри других стилей - не видны.
Например barry и bar
Что это? и как исправить?

```
.menu {
    display:block;
    margin:30px auto;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:$red;
    border:3px solid transparent;
    border-radius:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
    @include transition(all 0.5s ease-in-out);

    div.barry {
        width:40px;
        margin:35px auto;


        .bar {
            display:block;
            width:100%;
            height:5px;
            margin-top:3px;
            border-radius:2px;
            background-color:#fff;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Может дело в том, что это SCSS, а не CSS, и перед размещением на хостинге его нужно компилировать ?

Comment: понял. Пойду изучать SCSS